# Set up android view clickable

Tags: android, view, clickable

I set up splash activity which start another activity after few second. Anyway I wanted to add one more capability: to start the second activity not only after 5 second but after a click on my splash view.
As soon as I set up the next:

```
View v = (View)findViewById(R.layout.splash); 
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(v);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

my project does not run.
Where is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
public class SlashC extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener {
Thread timer;
MediaPlayer hTree;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = (View)findViewById(R.layout.splash); // problems start here
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(v);

    hTree = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy_tree);
    hTree.start();
    timer = new Thread(this);
    timer.start();

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent class2 = new Intent("com.roger.calc.MainActivity");
    startActivity(class2);
}
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        timer.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        Intent class2 = new Intent("com.roger.calc.MainActivity");
        startActivity(class2);
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    hTree.release();
    finish();
}}
```

And XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/splash2"
android:clickable="true" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the LinearLayout clickable by setting layout attribute `android:clickable="true"`, `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from xml or `setClickable(true)` from code. set onClickListener as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash2"/>
```

and in code part:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.splash)).setOnClickListener(this);

    /// YOUR CODE HERE
```

Comment: Also I added a **if statement** in my thread. Otherwise the second activity loaded twice.

Comment: you have android:clickable="true" twice in the xml above

Comment: why do we need to set something as clickable? Surely when we we add a listener it makes it clickable?

Answer (score 1):

may be you are missing this in your xml layout

```
android:id="@+id/splash"
```

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/splash2"
android:id="@+id/splash"
android:clickable="true" >
</LinearLayout>
```

setContentView(R.layout.name);

Linearlayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.splash);

v.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Rajesh use `Linearlayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.splash);`  instead of `Linearlayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.splash); `

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `findViewById(int id)` before `setContentView()` a layout inflater would be of help also set `android:clickable="true"`, `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on the layout.